# Почему всегда выводится 0?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>;
#include <iomanip>;
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian");
    int a, b, c; double e;
    printf("Введите a"); scanf_s("%i", &a);
    printf("Введите b"); scanf_s("%i", &b);
    printf("Введите c"); scanf_s("%i", &c);
        e = (a + b + c) / 3;

    printf("e=%d\n", e);
}
```

Почему всегда выводится 0?

Comment: Даже если закрыть глаза на `void main()`, неправильные `#include` и какие-то дикие `;` после  `#include`, программа имеет неопределенное поведение, а не "всегда выводится 0".

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, оно не компилируется.

Во-вторых, если исправить самые дурацкие ошибки (типа убрать `;` после `#include`, написать не `void main()`, а `int main()`), то 0 выводит не всегда, а когда не повезет.

Потому что
1. вы используете деление целочисленное, с отсечением дробной части.
2. вы выводите `double`, но используете спецификатор `%d`.

Делите так:

```
 e = (a + b + c) / 3.0;
```

а выводите -

```
printf("e = %lf\n", e);
```

Comment: Разве VS не компилирует `void main()`?

Comment: Кстати, а разве в новых VS инклюды не исправили? А то инклюдится `iostream` и `iomanip`, а используется `windows.h` и `cstdio`.